Problem to update a photo for an employee in AD though C#
I am trying to update a photo for the employees in AD using the following code:
public static void AddPictureToUser(string strFileName)
    {
    // Open file
    System.IO.FileStream inFile = new System.IO.FileStream(strFileName, System.IO.FileMode.Open, System.IO.FileAccess.Read);

    // Retrive Data into a byte array variable
    byte[] binaryData = new byte[inFile.Length];

    inFile.Close();

    string ldap = "LDAP://COMPANY.COM:389";

    string userAuthToMakeChanges = "user";

    string passwordUserAuthToMakeChanges = "password";

    string employeeUsername = "usernameToFind";

    System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry directoryEntry = new System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry(ldap, userAuthToMakeChanges, passwordUserAuthToMakeChanges, AuthenticationTypes.Secure);

    DirectorySearcher query = new DirectorySearcher(directoryEntry);

    query.PropertiesToLoad.Add("thumbnailPhoto");

    query.Filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName=" + employeeUsername + "))";

    SearchResult result = query.FindOne();

    System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry user = result.GetDirectoryEntry();

    // Clear existing picture if exists
    user.Properties["thumbnailPhoto"].Clear();

    // Update attribute with binary data from file
    user.Properties["thumbnailPhoto"].Add(binaryData);

    user.CommitChanges();
}

But I am receiving this error: System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryServicesCOMException: 'A constraint violation occurred.'
No more details
I don't think the problem is related with the access because I can change the employee data with though this tool. https://www.codetwo.com/freeware/active-directory-photos/?sts=1327 What do you think is happening? Thanks in advanced!


LDAP over SSL might have been configured, in which port 636 should be used. This might be checked according to the article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/active-directory/configure-ad-and-lds-event-logging.

LDAP updates might have been installed so that Channel Binding Token policy is in effect. If this policy set to Always your code should send CBT with the request. Other reasons might be LDAP signing requirement or authentication issues. You may check authentication from DC security logs. CBT and signing related log details may be found at the following article:


https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/2020-2023-and-2024-ldap-channel-binding-and-ldap-signing-requirements-for-windows-kb4520412-ef185fb8-00f7-167d-744c-f299a66fc00a
